BeforeEach not complete
enter image description here
I try to do a "before each" with a request to generate a customNumber and my before each doesn't want to go further.
BeforeEach:
beforeEach(async () => {
    const customerNumber = await createCustomerWithoutPID(
        firstName,
        lastname,
        email,
    )

    cy.log(customerNumber)
    const requestId = await generateRequestID(customerNumber)
    const generateJWT = await generateJWTtoken(customerNumber, requestId)
    cy.visit(
        `https://www.uat.telenet.be/nl/create-profile/?flow=completeProfile&jwt=${generateJWT}`,
    )
    cy.log('disable recaptcha')
    cy.turnOffRecaptcha()
})

Request:
export const createCustomerWithoutPID = async (
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    email: string,
): Promise<string> => {
    const env = Cypress.env('CYPRESS_ENV')

    const responseBody: Cypress.Response<CustomerResponse> = await new Promise(
        () => {
            cy.request({
                method: 'POST',
                url: `http://test-data-service.${env}.corp.telenet.be/api/customer-accounts`,
                headers: {
                    accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: {
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName,
                    emailAddress: email,
                },
            })
        },
    )
    return responseBody.body.customerNumber
}

I think my Promise is not solve correctly but I have no clue what is the best way with "await/async " syntax to solve this problem.... That is first step to generate a JWT token that i need for a link, first CustomerNumber than RequestId then Fetch this into xml Request and send so i can get my JWTToken.
If someone has an idea how I can refactor my code so my beforeeach works. I get the body of the request, but I need only the customerNumber and it doesn't show up.
I expect to return a customerBody of a response body but it never shows up

I think you would have to return the customerNumber by passing in resolve parameters and using it to extract responseBody.body.customerNumber.
There's no need for async/await inside this function
const createCustomerWithoutPID = (firstName:string, lastName:string, email:string) 
  : Promise<string> => {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      cy.request({...})
        .then(response => resolve(response.body.customerNumber)
    })


Than you for your answer, but i want to exclude the ".then()" if it is posible...that is why i really dont know how, i figured out somthing but idk if it is the right way

You have a phobia about .then? Cypress uses it a lot - if you can't get to grips with it, switch to Playwright which is all await and no .then.
